# How to create a dynamic dependent menu using <ul> and <li> tags in JSP MySql database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-boot, jsp

I am trying to implement a dynamic dependent dropdown list and these are basically category, tag and subcategory. I have created entities for category, tag and subactegory and all these have some data inside it that I have done from admin panel. Now I want to show it on my home page of web application. I already fetched category list from MySql database using Ajax. But I got stuck when need to get tags on the basis of category and further subcategory on the basis of category and tags. The category list is created using < ul > and < li> tags. I have done these things using  tag but I did not worked on **< li> or < ul>** tags to create dynamic dropdown.

I have fetched subcategory list. Through this I already get tags and category data as a response.

For more clear understanding:
**If I enter mouse on cake menu then there is a hover effect on it. So dropdown should be there with  sub menus.**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var url = "/api/getactivesubcategory";
        $.post(url, {
            
        }, function(data, status) {
            if (data.status == "OK") {
                if (data.statusCode == 1) {
                    var list = "";
                    var catlist = data.response;
                    var listlength = catlist.length;
                    if(listlength > 0){
                        for(var i = 0; i < listlength; i++){ 
                                var category = catlist[i].category.name;
                                list = list + "<li class=\"menu-dropdown\"><a href=\"#\">"+category+"<i class=\"ion-ios-arrow-down\"></i></a></li>";
                                if(category.length > 0){
                                    for(var j = 0; j < category.length; j++){
                                        var tag = catlist[j].tag.name;
                                        list = list + "<ul class=\"mega-menu-wrap\"><li><ul><li class=\"mega-menu-title\"><a href=\"#\">"+tag+"</a></li></ul></li></ul>";
                                        if(tag.length > 0){
                                            for(var k = 0; k < tag.length; k++){
                                                var subcat = catlist[k].name;
                                                list = list + "<li><a href=\"#\">"+subcat+"</a></li>";
                                            }
                                        } 
                                    }
                                }    
                        }
                    } 
                    document.getElementById('main-menu').innerHTML = list; 
                } else {
                    var error = data.responseMessage;
                    swal(error, "", "error");
                }
            } else {
                var error = data.responseMessage;
                swal(error, "", "error");
            }
        });
        
    });
```

I am little confuse that how should implement dynamic menu for home page in my spring boot web application. In the below screenshot I am getting output like this. But I want my menu result like in second screenshot. If anyone have any suggestions then please let me know.

[image: Screenshot to display menu]

[image: Screenshot to display desired output]

[image: Screenshot to display JSON data]

Comment: Hi, see if [this](https://codepen.io/nabeelfaheem/pen/GRRyQBv) works .

Comment: @Swati I am not sure that it work or not. As, need to fetch menu list from database and by using RESTApi and ajax, would be possible.

Comment: You need to generate your html like in that example then you can use same jquery/css code .

Comment: I have HTML of that and converted into JSP also.

Comment: Can you show json which is return from backend  ?

Comment: @Swati Yes, Sure. I will update my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234315/discussion-between-rakhi-sharma-and-swati).